# Latent Profile Analysis - standardizing the variables and interpreting it

Tags: latent-class, mplus

This is the first time I'm running an LPA and prior to running it, I standardized all variables because I read that would help interpret the profile structure later.

And now I'm confused in the interpretations; for example, is it right that in the solution below, both groups are lower than average on the purple item...? how does that make sense?

Really appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It just means in cluster 1 the purple item is about -0.5 on average, and in cluster 2 the purple item is about -0.2 on average. The values are the average values on the items for those classified into that profile.